# Angular unit test failing with error .catch is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have the following snippet of code that is part of a Component that is working fine the browser. But when I run my Karma/Jasmine unit test it's failing.

**Code:**

```
const request = this.queryQueue.pipe(switchMap(() => this.loadAppointments().catch(e => {
  return new Array<Appointment>();
})));

request.subscribe(
  newAppointments=> {
    this.appointments = this.myData.concat(newAppointments);
  }
);
```

**Notes:**

- queryQueue - is a Subject
- loadAppointments() - performs a web service request and returns Observable

**loadAppointments**

```
loadAppointments(): Observable<Appointment[]> {
  this.isLoading = true;
  return this.webApiService.getAppointments(this.getSearchDto(), this.appointments.length, 20);
}
```

**Goals:**

- Observable pipe is started by the queryQueue object
- Request data from server and appended to the current data list
- Stop long running requests from coming back after subsequent requests (hence the switchMap)
- Errors are handled in the catch

**Error:**

```
TypeError: _this.loadAppointments(...).catch is not a function
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (webpack:///./src/app/components/appointments/appointments.component.ts?:72:117)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (webpack:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/switchMap.js?:94:27)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (webpack:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js?:97:18)
    at Subject.next (webpack:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js?:66:25)
    at AppointmentsComponent.refresh (webpack:///./src/app/components/appointments/appointments.component.ts?:84:25)
    at AppointmentsComponent.set [as day] (webpack:///./src/app/components/appointments/appointments.component.ts?:42:18)
    at AppointmentsComponent.gotoToday (webpack:///./src/app/components/appointments/appointments.component.ts?:111:18)
    at AppointmentsComponent.ngOnInit (webpack:///./src/app/components/appointments/appointments.component.ts?:64:14)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:12585:19)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14109:20)
```

**Unit Test:**

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppointmentsComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        InfiniteScrollModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: WebApiService, useClass: MockWebApiService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppointmentsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

/* ...Code missing for brevity... */

class MockWebApiService {
  getAppointments(): Observable<Appointment[]> { return of([]);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the test throws on the first test case, your code sample must be either in `constructor` or `ngOnInit`. If it's in the constructor please move it to `ngOnInit` as it will make testing much easier.

It's throwing because `switchMap` expects `this.loadAppointments()` to return an observable, but it doesn't. You need to mock this method in order to test your componenent.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppointmentsComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  component.loadAppointments = () => of([]);

  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

This simple change should stop the test from failing so early. You can also consider spying on the `loadAppointment` method with `jasmine.spy`, but it really depends on what you are testing for.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't quite do it. loadAppointments() calls into another service that returns an Observable<Appointment[]>. I am mocking that method (which I've now included in an edit to the question). I did also try just mocking the loadAppointments method directly, as you suggested, but that still resulted in the same error.

Comment: @CalebSeadon - Did you ever get this to work? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: @ShivaNaru sorry, this was so many years ago. I can't recall what I did in the end